# Cannot declare a variable in a variadic template using metaprogramming

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am using a variadic template function to perform a function for each argument. The iteration uses metaprogramming, but there is a problem: I cannot declare a simple variable in it. Here is an example:

```
template < size_t I = 0, typename... Args >
auto recursive_function( std::tuple< Args... > const& t )
    -> typename std::enable_if< I == sizeof...(Args), void >::type
{

}


template < size_t I = 0, typename... Args >
auto recursive_function( std::tuple< Args...>const & t )
    -> typename std::enable_if< I < sizeof...(Args), void >::type
{
    cout << get<I>(t) << endl;
    recursive_function< I + 1, Args... >( t );
}
```

These functions work well for displaying any argument, but if we change the code a little bit ...

```
template < size_t I = 0, typename... Args >
auto recursive_function( std::tuple< Args... > const& t )
    -> typename std::enable_if< I == sizeof...(Args), void >::type
{

}


template < size_t I = 0, typename... Args >
auto recursive_function( std::tuple< Args...>const & t )
    -> typename std::enable_if< I < sizeof...(Args), void >::type
{
    cout << get<I>(t) << endl;

    // Just a simple declaration added...
    int i = 0;

    recursive_function< I + 1, Args... >( t );
}
```

[EDIT]
The compiler complains:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type recursive_function(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with long unsigned int I = 0ul; Args = {int, int, int, int, int}; typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type = void]':

main.cpp:524:31:   required from here

main.cpp:511:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
 int i=0;
     ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type recursive_function(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with long unsigned int I = 1ul; Args = {int, int, int, int, int}; typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type = void]':

main.cpp:512:45:   required from 'typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type recursive_function(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with long unsigned int I = 0ul; Args = {int, int, int, int, int}; typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type = void]'

main.cpp:524:31:   required from here

main.cpp:511:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]

main.cpp: In instantiation of 'typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type recursive_function(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with long unsigned int I = 2ul; Args = {int, int, int, int, int}; typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type = void]':

main.cpp:512:45:   recursively required from 'typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type recursive_function(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with long unsigned int I = 1ul; Args = {int, int, int, int, int}; typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (Tp ...)), void>::type = void]'
```

It is just an example (there is no reason in declaring a variable this way...), but I would like to understand what this error means.

Does anybody have an idea?

[EDIT2] Here is the working code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>


using namespace std;


template < size_t I = 0, typename... Args >
auto recursive_function( std::tuple< Args... > const& t )
    -> typename std::enable_if< I == sizeof...(Args), void >::type
{

}


template < size_t I = 0, typename... Args >
auto recursive_function( std::tuple< Args...>const & t )
    -> typename std::enable_if< I < sizeof...(Args), void >::type
{
    cout << get<I>(t) << endl;
    int i = 0;
    recursive_function< I + 1, Args... >( t );
}



int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    try
    {
        auto t = make_tuple(1,2,3,4,5);

        recursive_function( t );
    }
    catch( std::exception& e )
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The entire error message is above.
The compiler version used is GCC 4.8.2, with the option std=c++1y, and I am using Code::Blocks. The weird thing is that build has finished with 2 errors and 15 warnings, but the actual output takes into account the changes (so that the error is not taken into account?)

Comment: Can you post the error message? It contains the information on what's wrong.

Comment: Ok I will edit the main message

Comment: Possibly silly question: have you tried taking the broken code and removing the simple declaration to see if it starts working again?

Comment: Of course, and it works! This is not the question I want the answer though... Why does this declaration stop the compilation?

Comment: That's not the full error message, I am afraid. It lacks a starting point - *what* is recursively required.

Comment: Please show a complete example.  [my attempt to reproduce your problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d445507bf31ae464) produced only a warning.  Please list your compiler, version, code that actually reproduces your problem (ie, minimal code that when compiled, with NO OTHER CODE, generates the error), and include the actual error message (not just notes on the error message).  -1, inform me when your question has been fixed and I will revert it.  Of course, at this point, I guess your problem is a wall "error".

Comment: @Mathieu: It *could have been* the answer to the question -- I've seen more than enough instances where someone asks a question like this and the problem turns out to be that they made a second change somewhere else on accident.

Comment: ok yakk, I will post a working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a variable and did not use it.

You have all warnings enabled (`-Wall`) and warnings-as-errors enabled.  As creating a pointless variable is usually a sign you made a mistake, the compiler has a warning for it.

So a warning (you created a variable and did not use it) generated an error, which it then gave details about how this error came about (the template instantiations wrapping its instantiation as an unused variable).

Insert `(void)i;` on the next line, and the warning goes away.

Note that warnings-as-errors is a good plan, keep it on, and also keep on `-Wall` (activate all warnings).  Your problem was that you failed to track down what the real error was, you where distracted by the template expansion notes that the compiler was providing.

Comment: It appears that the only difference we have is that you use clang and not g++, and also that the option std==c++1z is available in your version... Does this option throw away the warnings-as-errors?

Comment: And ok for the explanation, I knew how to fix it but I did not know the warnings-as-errors.